# how to pass a complex type using the Navigation framework

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

How does one pass a complex object to the target `Page` using the `NavigationService.Navigate` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that.  It kind of makes sense, because the idea is to provide deep linking support for pages/views, but it's definitely annoying that you can't do it.  The options you have are:

- For small objects, you *could* serialise them and pass them to the next view in the query string, although I'd recommend against that approach (different browsers have different number of maximum characters in a URL that they support, and also the object may be out of date if the user bookmarks that page and returns to it).
- Store the object in a global cache, from which the view being navigated to can access it.  Not nice, but it will work.
- The Navigation Framework source code is a part of the Silverlight Toolkit.  You *could* modify this to support complex objects, but I'd strongly recommend against doing so.
- Use the MVVM pattern, with one view model used to manage multiple views, and therefore the object would be available to all those views.

Hope this helps...

Chris

P.S. I discuss this in my book [Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272074), although only in as much depth as above as there's not a particularly nice solution to the problem :).

Comment: Great book by the way.  In this particular case, I ended up taking option 2, although not happy about it.